# Stock spilt not reflected in historical data

Tags: historical-data, split

According to this [article](https://www.cultofmac.com/282891/aapl-stock-splits-7-1-opens-trading-92/), Apple's stock split 7:1 on June 9, 2014. The stock supposedly closed at around \$645 on June 6 and was supposed to open at around \$92 on June 9. I confirmed that a split took place on June 9 through [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?period1=1401595200&period2=1402545600&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d); however, according to the historical data table shown there, the closing price on June 6 was \$92.22 and the closing price on June 9 was \$93.70. (These are the regular closing prices, not adjusted. The adjusted closing prices are \$84.85 and \$86.21 for June 6 and June 9, respectively.) My understanding was that the regular closing prices are not adjusted for splits while adjusted closing prices are. If this is true, why is the \$645 closing price not shown in the chart on Yahoo Finance on the days leading up to the split?

Comment: There are numerous posts in this forum pointing out data quality problems with Yahoo Finance. (And since  it is a free data source, it is perhaps not so surprising...).

Comment: Thanks, @AlexC. Was great to find that out. I am looking into other data sources now.